# How to save values from a gridview using extjs

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I created a gridview with textfield inside in every cell programmatically, I need to get all the values of the textfields and save them.

This is my code:

```js
renderColumn : function(value, meta, record, rowIndex)  {
  var columnaId   = value;
  var filaId    = record.raw.tipoCuenta.numero;
  return '<input type="text" size=18 maxlength=18 style="text-align:right; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important; font-weight:bold; font-size:10px;" value="' 
    + record.get(meta.column.campoValor)
    + '" tabindex="' + tabindex + '" class= "' + columnaId + '_' + filaId + '"></input>'
    +'<input type="text" size=5 maxlength=5 style="border : white; text-align:right; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important; font-size:10px;" value="'
    + record.get(meta.column.campoPorcentaje)
    + '" readonly="readonly" class= "porcentaje">% </input>';   
 },
```

This is the view.

[Gridview example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fWWs.jpg)

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS do you use? Does your version of ExtJS have a [`widgetcolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html)?

Comment: Yes, I use gridPanel.

Comment: The version is 4.0 , let me check, thank you.

Comment: How about applying a common class to all inputs and then using `grid.getView().getEl().query('.input-class-name')`

Comment: Hello, I solved using onblur, call a function that set the record, and modify my service, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would

- bind a store to your grid
- bind each column to a corresponding field using the `dataIndex` config
- include the `cellediting` plugin on the grid
- add an editor to each column

This would programmatically update the store records as you entered values.

Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/20mk&view/editor) for an example of a grid with cellediting.